# Error when trying to run simple kivy program in pycharm

Tags: python, kivy, python-3.7, kivy-language

I have tried to run this code:

```
kivy.require('1.11.1')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

But I receive this error message:

```
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0rc3, git-20c14b2, 20200615
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Emmy\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 16:30:00) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Emmy\kivy_venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 185 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer, img_gif ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: Det går inte att hitta den angivna modulen.
  File "C:\Users\Emmy\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 62, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\Emmy\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

I am using pycharm and have installed: Kivy, kivy-deps.glew, kivy-deps.gstreamer, kivy-deps.sdl2, pygame and pillow.

I am using python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

Already got this error, it worked after i updated pycharm and created a new environnement for Kivy only.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLlFl.jpg

You also need to import kivy to use require.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

kivy.require('1.11.1')


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```